# RNAs arising from intergenic regions

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, genomics

Which type of RNA molecule is coded for in intergenic regions? I think it must be a non-coding RNA but I'm unsure which type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term intergenic is more or less obsolete now. In fact it is ironical to say that a gene, which can give rise to a functional protein or an RNA, is expressed from an intergenic region. However the usage continues for both lncRNAs and miRNAs (other major type of ncRNA in metazoans<sup>**1**</sup> - piRNAs have different classification). lncRNAs are vaguely classified as sense-overlapping (expressed in the same direction as a known gene but not completely overlapping), antisense (expressed from the antisense strand of a known gene) or intergenic; similarly miRNAs are classified as intronic or intergenic.

It is not necessary that the intergenic RNA has to be strictly non-coding, it can be coding as well; a novel protein.

In all these cases the term intergenic means - not overlapping with a **known** gene. Better nomenclature is necessary as the field of genomics makes more progress.

See this [article](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/17/6/669.full).

<sup>**1**</sup> Most metazoans.